# adding click signal to any QWidget doesn't support it

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

I was in deep need to make my QLineEdit clear itself as soon as user click to it , but I found that no signal clicked supported to QLineEdit , so I searched until I found code below to perform task , it works fine but I found it also response to Key Board Press event not only mouse click event , I can't Explain why !!! , so anyone can help !!!

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

def clickable(widget):

    class Filter(QObject):

        clicked = pyqtSignal()

        def eventFilter(self, obj, event):

            if obj == widget:
                if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                    if obj.rect().contains(event.pos()):
                        self.clicked.emit()
                        return True

            return False

    filter = Filter(widget)
    widget.installEventFilter(filter)
    return filter.clicked
```

Comment: I have tested your code and only the signal is emitted when pressed with the mouse.

Comment: Have you tested on QlineEdit or something else?

Comment: Yes, with the QLineEdit, that is my test: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/6ecdcaf3ad0fbd90edc59468549e39d8

Comment: Your code look close to mine but with me it reacted with every click on mouse or key on key board

Comment: I doubt it, I think you have implemented it badly. You could share your complete code.

Comment: Yes you alright , it was a problem in my IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code go right , problem was in my IDE